# WiX Using Wildcards in Directory Paths

Tags: wix, wix3.6, wix3.7

Basically the issue is I have one file which I want to install to many directories which may or may not exist. Many of the directories have similar structures which vary only based on platform or version. Instead of making a variable for each possible version and platform and a component for each configuration, I'd like to use some form of a wildcard to install the file to any path having the REGEX structure. Some examples follow.

Example Actual Paths:

```
C:\Program Files\Some App\v. 10\bin\
C:\Program Files\Some App\v. 12\bin\
C:\Program Files (x 86)\Some App\v. 9\bin\
C:\Program Files\Other App v. 12\bin\
C:\Program Files (x 86)\Other App v. 14\bin\
```

Example of what I'd like to use as a destination directory:

```
C:\Program Files*\Some App\v. *\bin\
C:\Program Files*\Other App v. *\bin\
```

Please note that the directory structure is not defined by me, I am simply installing my application as a plug-in to the other application and I need to copy a configuration file. Also the actual file path is more complicated and it is unlikely (near impossible) that I will accidentally install my file in a location it should not go. As well, even if that happens it won't break anything.

Is this possible?

Edit: Also if installation of the file fails because the directory doesn't exist, I do not want the overall installation to fail. Non-existing paths are perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily reach that by using CustomAction (where you manage this in a C#, C++, ... method). As far as I know WIX does not have any direct support of wildcards in the folders structure.

There is also a tool for generating folder tree structure called Paraffin (you can get a download link here http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jrobbins/paraffin-3-6-now-keeping-custom-added-namespaces ) but this only works for existing structures which, if I understand your problem well, is not your case.

Comment: We are looking to move away from WIX because it is missing this critical feature.  When you are dealing with thousands of files, it is not practical to try and manage that manually.  Wildcards are an absolute must for some projects.